# Where can I get images for a 'loading' progress bar?

Tags: image, progress-bar, spinner, loading, progress

I am building a site with jquery.  This site is all about numbers, statistics and progress so I created it mostly with progress bar to indicate the totals.  At the moment I changed the progress bar into different colors, but am wondering if anyone knows a site where I can find nice images for the progress bar?  I have searched google but can't seem to find any descent one.

Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a large variety of basic animated "waiting" icons on http://www.ajaxload.info

For more complex ones, try http://preloaders.net or http://www.loadinfo.net

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an open source Windoze installer such as NSIS http://nsis.sourceforge.net and it's associated plugins such as http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LoadingBar_UI ?